# Laravel 5.2 - Mailing a variable as html

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm using the Laravel `Mail::raw` facade to send an email as I don't have a view setup to pass to `Mail`. So my code looks like -

```
  Mail::raw($emailBody, function ($message) {
      $message->from('clients@test.co.uk');
      $message->to('test@.co.uk');
  });
```

My variable `$emailBody` contains a full table complete with tr and text of course when the email is sent it doesn't render the HTML stored within my variable as I'm using RAW.

is there a way to pass my variable to the email but instead of raw use html, still without building a view to use as the email template.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail) it seems that the ::raw method for Mail is to be used for raw strings such as a literal string like in their example:

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function ($message) {
    //
});
```

I think you want to use the regular send method and utilize how they are sending an array as the first argument which calls the html file (this is useful because you could make multiple templates), read this part of the docs:

> By default, the view given to the send method is assumed to contain HTML. However, by passing an array as the first argument to
>   the send method, you may specify a plain text view to send in addition
>   to the HTML view:
>
> ```
> Mail::send(['html.view', 'text.view'], $data, $callback);
> ```

Then you can create the blade the same way you would normally and use the $data arg to send your dynamic information.